# How to use soap class in php (with example)?

Tags: php, soap

I would like to learn the basic usage of SOAP through this ([weather](http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?op=GetWeather)) example.
How is it worthy to process this data?

Request:

```
POST /globalweather.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.webservicex.net
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <GetWeather xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
      <CityName>string</CityName>
      <CountryName>string</CountryName>
    </GetWeather>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
```

Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <GetWeatherResponse xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
      <GetWeatherResult>string</GetWeatherResult>
    </GetWeatherResponse>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

Comment: @Topener I found information about it but not a toturial. Esecially not for php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php . If you post a great toturial I'll accept your answer (By great I mean: with that I can do this example)

Comment: Topener, I disagree. This site is for programming related questions, not only for code. As far as the question isn't too open-ended it should be fine. Great answers to this question would be links to useful resources, in the manual and elsewhere, or maybe a simple example.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The most simple approach would be:

```
$requestParams = array(
    'CityName' => 'Berlin',
    'CountryName' => 'Germany'
);

$client = new SoapClient('http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?WSDL');
$response = $client->GetWeather($requestParams);

print_r($response);
```

would output

```
stdClass Object
(
    [GetWeatherResult] => <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<CurrentWeather>
  <Location>Berlin-Tegel, Germany (EDDT) 52-34N 013-19E 37M</Location>
  <Time>Jan 26, 2012 - 07:50 AM EST / 2012.01.26 1250 UTC</Time>
  <Wind> from the SE (130 degrees) at 14 MPH (12 KT):0</Wind>
  <Visibility> greater than 7 mile(s):0</Visibility>
  <SkyConditions> mostly clear</SkyConditions>
  <Temperature> 33 F (1 C)</Temperature>
  <Wind>Windchill: 23 F (-5 C):1</Wind>
  <DewPoint> 21 F (-6 C)</DewPoint>
  <RelativeHumidity> 59%</RelativeHumidity>
  <Pressure> 30.27 in. Hg (1025 hPa)</Pressure>
  <Status>Success</Status>
</CurrentWeather>
)
```

The rest can then be parsed with SimpleXML or something similar.

Note, that the kind of response is specific to this web service. There are better web services out there, which do not simply return an xml string, but rather provide the response structure within the WSDL.

---

**EDIT** An example for a "more structured" webservice could be the GeoIP lookup on the same site:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL');
$result = $client->GetGeoIP(array('IPAddress' => '8.8.8.8'));

print_r($result);
```

this gives you:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [GetGeoIPResult] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ReturnCode] => 1
            [IP] => 8.8.8.8
            [ReturnCodeDetails] => Success
            [CountryName] => United States
            [CountryCode] => USA
        )

)
```

Now you can simply access the values by invoking

```
$country = $result->GetGeoIPResult->CountryName;
```

Comment: Great answer, the offcial php docs http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php suck. Event after reading your answer I can't find where your method is described in the manual but it works for me, thanks.

Comment: @Ekonoval : My method is not documented, because the method names `GetGeoIP()` and `GetWeather()` are not "real" methods of the SoapClient, but they are called via the magic `__call()` method. The names of the methods are defined in the WSDL file.