# accessing SOAP via PHP

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I've got a website which needs to send a request to another server and retrieve some data. I don't know anything about SOAP, so I need an expert help here.

Here is the data the second server is giving me.
    I dont know where to start and how to do it. So any help is appreciated.
    Could you give me a working example of php code which works with this code.

SOAP 1.1

The following is a sample SOAP 1.1 request and response. The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values.

```
POST /Service1.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: puanreport.retail.az
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/_find"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <_find xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <par>string</par>
    </_find>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <_findResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <_findResult>
        <bon>
          <Cari_Kod>string</Cari_Kod>
          <Puan>string</Puan>
        </bon>
        <bon>
          <Cari_Kod>string</Cari_Kod>
          <Puan>string</Puan>
        </bon>
      </_findResult>
    </_findResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use soap class in php (with example)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018236/how-to-use-soap-class-in-php-with-example)

Answer (score 0):

The most simple approach would be:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL');
$result = $client->GetGeoIP(array('IPAddress' => '8.8.8.8'));

print_r($result);
```

this gives you:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [GetGeoIPResult] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ReturnCode] => 1
            [IP] => 8.8.8.8
            [ReturnCodeDetails] => Success
            [CountryName] => United States
            [CountryCode] => USA
        )

)
```

Now you can simply access the values by invoking

```
$country = $result->GetGeoIPResult->CountryName;
```

Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018236/how-to-use-soap-class-in-php-with-example)

[php.net soap class](http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php)