# Extract xml data from soap response using php

Tags: php, xml, soap

I know this has been asked many many times but I haven't been able to get any of the suggestions to work with my situation and I have searched the web and here and tried everything and anything and nothing works.  How can i extract the availability data from this xml string using php.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soap:Body>
      <GetSessionAvailabilityResponse xmlns="http://www.resv5.com/webservices">
         <GetSessionAvailabilityResult>
            <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/WebAvail.xsd" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/WebAvail.xsd" id="WebAvail" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/WebAvail.xsd" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
               <xs:element name="WebAvail" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:Locale="en-US">
                  <xs:complexType>
                     <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xs:element name="Availability">
                           <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:sequence>
                                 <xs:element name="ID" msdata:AutoIncrement="true" msdata:AutoIncrementSeed="1" type="xs:int" />
                                 <xs:element name="PlanTime" type="xs:dateTime" />
                                 <xs:element name="Available" type="xs:boolean" />
                                 <xs:element name="ReturnTime" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                              </xs:sequence>
                           </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="SessionMessage">
                           <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:sequence>
                                 <xs:element name="ID" msdata:AutoIncrement="true" msdata:AutoIncrementSeed="1" type="xs:int" />
                                 <xs:element name="Message" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                 <xs:element name="CardRequired" type="xs:boolean" default="false" />
                              </xs:sequence>
                           </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                     </xs:choice>
                  </xs:complexType>
                  <xs:unique name="PK_Availability" msdata:PrimaryKey="true">
                     <xs:selector xpath=".//mstns:Availability" />
                     <xs:field xpath="mstns:ID" />
                  </xs:unique>
                  <xs:unique name="PK_SessionMessage" msdata:PrimaryKey="true">
                     <xs:selector xpath=".//mstns:SessionMessage" />
                     <xs:field xpath="mstns:ID" />
                  </xs:unique>
               </xs:element>
            </xs:schema>
            <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
               <WebAvail xmlns="http://tempuri.org/WebAvail.xsd">
                  <Availability diffgr:id="Availability1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
                     <ID>1</ID>
                     <PlanTime>1900-01-01T19:00:00+00:00</PlanTime>
                     <Available>false</Available>
                  </Availability>
                  <Availability diffgr:id="Availability2" msdata:rowOrder="1" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
                     <ID>2</ID>
                     <PlanTime>1900-01-01T19:30:00+00:00</PlanTime>
                     <Available>false</Available>
                  </Availability>
                  <Availability diffgr:id="Availability3" msdata:rowOrder="2" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
                     <ID>3</ID>
                     <PlanTime>1900-01-01T20:00:00+00:00</PlanTime>
                     <Available>false</Available>
                  </Availability>
                  <Availability diffgr:id="Availability4" msdata:rowOrder="3" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
                     <ID>4</ID>
                     <PlanTime>1900-01-01T20:30:00+00:00</PlanTime>
                     <Available>false</Available>
                  </Availability>
                  <Availability diffgr:id="Availability5" msdata:rowOrder="4" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
                     <ID>5</ID>
                     <PlanTime>1900-01-01T21:00:00+00:00</PlanTime>
                     <Available>false</Available>
                  </Availability>
                  <Availability diffgr:id="Availability6" msdata:rowOrder="5" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
                     <ID>6</ID>
                     <PlanTime>1900-01-01T21:30:00+00:00</PlanTime>
                     <Available>false</Available>
                  </Availability>
                  <SessionMessage diffgr:id="SessionMessage1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
                     <ID>1</ID>
                     <Message />
                     <CardRequired>false</CardRequired>
                  </SessionMessage>
               </WebAvail>
            </diffgr:diffgram>
         </GetSessionAvailabilityResult>
      </GetSessionAvailabilityResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Do you mean the <availability> tag or the <xs:element:"Availability"> ?

Answer (score 0):

This is generated by [SOAP protocol](http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/ws_soap_intro.asp).

read more here(maybe duplicate question): [How to use soap class in php (with example)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018236/how-to-use-soap-class-in-php-with-example)

Comment: I understand how to extract xml from a standard xml string. Its the specific example that I looking for help with.

Comment: @MatthewHanson yes, you right. sorry. I edited my answer. hope this help.