# How to configure soap service and call it from PHP application

Tags: c#, php, soap

I have a c# project which generate a service with this command

```
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe EnqueteEnLigneSch.exe
```

and Then in the PHP appilcation i'm calling the service like this :

```
define('url_wsdl',"http://localhost:8734/serviceSVC?singleWsdl");
```

But it is not working, well i'm confused in how to set the enpoint configuration, this is how im doing it now:

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="simplecalculmexcomport" name="WcfsaveRepES.service">
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:8734/serviceSVC" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
        name="simplecalculhttpservice" contract="WcfsaveRepES.Iservice" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
        name="simplecalculmexpservice" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
       <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8734/serviceSVC" />

      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
```

Well is it a call problem? or a configuration problem ?
any help? and thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough reputation to comment, so I am going to post as an answer.

Here is a link to a similar question on stackoverflow: [How to use soap class in php (with example)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018236/how-to-use-soap-class-in-php-with-example)

In general, your typical request and response would be like:

```
$requestParams = array(
'Number1' => '14',
'Number2' => '31'
);

$client = new SoapClient('http://localhost:8734/serviceSVC?singleWsdl');
$result = $client->GetSum($requestParams);

print_r($result);
```

where the service is a basic calculator.

Comment: Well thanks but i already tried to add singleWsdl but it is not working too

Comment: I'm noticing there is no .svc extension in your service url. If you put that url in your browser, are you able to see the wsdl?

If you are still starting your project, have you considered making your service REST-based? You get better inter-operability across different programming languages and it's not too difficult with a Visual Studio WebApi project or some configuration on your WCF service

Comment: well if i use it like this "http://-myaddress-ip:8734/serviceSVC?singleWsdl" i'm able to see the wsdl File. However it is a project for the compoany and i just made some modifications and want to test it locally ( every thing work fine in the server) so i can"t made big change sliek soap -> rest